# Result of loop is undefined

Tags: javascript

Function argument is stored in such format

```
["2015-07-05 00:30", 59]
...
["2015-07-05 01:00", 62]
```

```js
function generateCSV(timeAndValue) {
    object = {}
    var zero = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < timeAndValue.length; i++){
        var value = timeAndValue[i]
        var days = moment(value[0]).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        obj[days] += value[1] + ', '
    }
}
```

In the loop object takes days as parameter and the amount of value spent on that day.
2015-07-05:

> "2015-07-05: "undefined59, 62, 65...
>
> 2015-07-06: "undefined61, 61, 60..."

Every parameter value is beginning with "undefined". How can I loop that parameters wouldn't begin with "undefined"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
obj[days] += value[1] + ', '
```

with

```
if (obj[days]===undefined) obj[days] = ''; 
obj[days] += value[1] + ', '
```

so that you don't add a string to `undefined`.

But instead of adding `", "` after every values, you could also build an array in your loop:

```
if (obj[days]===undefined) obj[days] = []; 
obj[days].push(value[1])
```

and then use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) at the end to avoid the trailing comma (and on the general principle that string building should be deferred to the rendering time).

Be careful to variable declarations: `object` might be OK, assuming it's defined in a just outside scope, but the missing declaration of `i` is very dangerous, as it's probable it's not the only `i` in your application.

Edit: as seen by James, you have a typo, it's either "object" or "obj".

Comment: I think there's also a mismatch between `object = {}` and `obj[days]`

Comment: because otherwise you're about to throw away `obj[days]` as soon as the loop goes round - I think those results should be being stored in the `object` variable that's been defined at the start of the function

Comment: @JamesThorpe Oh, you mean there's a typo "object" vs "obj". I hadn't seen it. Yes, you're right (and I hope it's just in the question, not in the real code, just like the floating `zero`).

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I should have said between `object = {}` and `obj`.  Unless of course `obj` is defined elsewhere.  Given that `object` doesn't explicitly have `var` before it, who knows...!

Comment: Thank you very much it is working.  Denys Séguret was right he even gave me the code which suits to my code ) object = {} was obj ={} in my code ).